# Eval Function TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a TSQL function that allows to validate an operation? Example:

`Select (1 = 0)` should return `false` while `Select (1 = 1)` should return `true`

or

`Select ('a' = 'b')` should return `false` while `Select ('a' = 'a')` should return `true`

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type. You're really just trying to do `select case when 1=1 then 1 else 0 end as logicaltest;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `BIT` datatype to represent `boolean data`. A `BIT` field's value is either `1,0 or null`.

In SQL you use `0` and `1` to set a bit field (just as a yes/no field in Access). In SQL Server Management Studio it displays as a `True/False` value (at least in recent versions).

When accessing the database through ASP.NET it will expose the field as a boolean value. Thanks @guffa, This answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server)

Example:

```
DECLARE 
    @strBoolean NVARCHAR(1000),
    @strSQL NVARCHAR(1000),
    @bResult BIT = 0

SET @strBoolean = N'(1=1)'     --returns 1, it means True
--SET @strBoolean = N'(1=0)'   --returns 0, it means False

SET @strSQL = N'SELECT @bCheck = 1 WHERE '+@strBoolean 
EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL, N'@bCheck INT OUT', @bResult OUT

SELECT 
    (CASE @bResult
          WHEN 1 THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False'
     END)
     result
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Phil, there's no Boolean data type in SQL Server. So, we need the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve in order to suggest an alternative.

Returning the string "false" is very different from returning a Boolean value of false (if SQL server had supported Boolean types in the first place), which is why we need a context.

Answer (score 0):

There is not boolean **data type** in SQL Server. This means you can't return a bool as a column from a `SELECT` and you can't store a boolean value on a table. However, it's very common to use `BIT` or `VARCHAR` data types to *represent* boolean values. They are not boolean per se, you need to compare them against something to actually use them as a boolean.

With this in mind, you **can't** use a column directly as a filter:

```
DECLARE @BitValue BIT = 1 -- We assume that 1 represents "true" boolean value

SELECT 1 WHERE @BitValue
-- An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@BitValue'.
```

You will have to compare the column against something to make the result a boolean the engine can use:

```
DECLARE @BitValue BIT = 1

SELECT 'OK!' WHERE @BitValue = 1 -- Boolean result
-- Result: OK!
```

---

This doesn't mean that SQL Server doesn't use boolean logic. These are needed whenever you write filtering or conditional expressions. These are a few:

- `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses must resort to true/false results:

  ```
  SELECT ... 
  WHERE Column = 'SomeValue' -- Boolean result

  SELECT ... 
  HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNT(DISTINCT(Column)) -- Boolean result
  ```
- Inside `CASE` expressions true/false results determine which value to return:

  ```
  SELECT CASE 
      WHEN Column = 1 -- Boolean result
          THEN 'Value 1'
      WHEN Column <> 2 -- Boolean result
          THEN 'Value 2' END

  SELECT CASE Column
      WHEN 1 -- Boolean result (Column = 1)
          THEN 'Value 1'
      WHEN 2 -- Boolean result (Column = 2)
          THEN 'Value 2' END
  ```
- `IF` statements conditionally executes blocks of statements:

  ```
  IF @Variable IS NOT NULL -- Boolean result
  BEGIN

      -- Statements

  END
  ```
- `IN` expressions are just a syntactic sugar of `OR` operands:

  ```
  Column IN ('Value 1', 'Value 2', AnotherColumn) -- Boolean result
  ```
- `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` return true/false depending if the result set contains at least 1 row:

  ```
  EXISTS (SELECT ...) -- Boolean result
  ```

In most places where boolean results are needed, you can chain logical operators such as `AND` or `OR`.